# Trying to align images in <td>

Tags: html

I recently got into email coding and I've never used Tables before. I'm trying to align these 4 social Icons at the top of the email, but I cannot figure it out. I tried googling some stuff on Tables and I thought I had a pretty good grasp on it.

The four Social icons pop out of my table that is currently set to 600 width.

I feel pretty bad, this must be an easy question....

```
Thanks for <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table style="margin: 0 auto;" width="600">
        <tr>
        <td width="400" align="left" valign="top">View this mailing in your web browser</td>
        <td width:"19" align="right" valign="top"><img src="img/facebook-icon.png" width="19"></td>
        <td width:"19" align="right" valign="top"><img src="img/facebook-icon.png" width="19"></td>
        <td width:"19" align="right" valign="top"><img src="img/facebook-icon.png" width="19"></td>
        <td width:"19" align="right" valign="top"><img src="img/facebook-icon.png" width="19"></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
      <td width:"19" width="600;"><img src="img/breaker.png"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The colon is not a valid attribute-value separator in html. All those "width:'19'" parts are doing exactly nothing. Also, don't put semicolons after values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<td colspan="5">` in the second row:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="5" width="600"><img src="img/breaker.png"></td>
</tr>
```

Colspan basically tells browser that this `<td>` has width of 5 columns, i.e. 5 "regular" `<td>` elements. [More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan).

Also, I've removed duplicate `width` attribute you've had there.